# Send RequestParameter from jsp in Spring MVC application

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'category' is not present

in my controller i've used this code

```
           @RequestMapping
              public String getVendors(@RequestParam String 
              category,ModelMap map) {

           map.put("category", category);
           return "vendors";
         }
```

Comment: Update your jsp code here...

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a parameter, if it's a GET request you can have it in the link

```
<a href="./getVendors?category=CATEGORY_VALUE">CATEGORY VALUE</a>
```

PS
You should use spring:url tag instead but I think the script above keep things clear

Comment: <td><a href="./vendors?category=${prs.category}">Vendor</a></td>
i'm using this but not working !

Answer (score 0):

you can try following code

```
<a href="/dwfile?id=1>RequestUrl</a>



@RequestMapping(value = "/dwfile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String doDownload(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response,   @RequestParam("id") String id) {


}
```